# ReferenceError: expressValidator is not defined Express , ejs, Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am trying to make validation form using Express and node. I am very new to all this and I am getting this error in my console

> ReferenceError: expressValidator is not defined

**index.js code**

```
var express = require('express'),
 bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
 validator = require('express-validator'),
 routes = require('./routes'),
 path = require('path'),
 ejs = require('ejs'),
 app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(expressValidator());

//post
app.post('/signup', routes.registerUser);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('view options', {layout: false});


//get
app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/signup', routes.signup);
app.get('/login', routes.login);

app.listen(3000,function(){
  console.log("Server running at Port 3000");
});
```

In routes folder i have only one js file **index.js**

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.render('index');
};
exports.signup = function(req, res){
  res.render('signup');
};
exports.login = function(req, res){
  res.render('index');
};

exports.registerUser = function(req, res){
    req.check('uname', 'Username is required').notEmpty();
    req.check('fname', 'First name is required').notEmpty();
    req.check('lname', 'Last name is required').notEmpty();
    req.check('email', 'Email is required').notEmpty();
    req.check('mob', 'Mobile Number is required').notEmpty();
    req.check('add', 'Address is required').notEmpty();
    req.check('city', 'City is required').notEmpty();
    req.check('url', 'URL is required').notEmpty();
    req.check('pcode', 'PIN code is required').notEmpty();
    req.check('password', 'Password is required').notEmpty();

    var errors = req.validationErrors();

    if(errors){
        console.log("There may be errors");
        res.redirect('signup');
    }else{
        var uname = req.body.uname;
        var user = {
            'fname' : req.body.uname,
            'lname' : req.body.lname,
            'email' : req.body.email,
            'mob' : req.body.mob,
            'add' : req.body.add,
            'url' : req.body.url,
            'pcode' : req.body.pcode,
            'password' : req.body.password
        };

    }
};
```

When I run the application I got this every time

> app.use(expressValidator());
>       ^
>   ReferenceError: expressValidator is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
app.use(expressValidator());
```

to

```
app.use(validator());
```

Comment: can you tell me why `app.use(expressValidator());`
it's not working.

Comment: Because you did not define expressValidator, you import express validator as validattor instead of expressValidator:  ```validator = require('express-validator')```

Comment: `var errors = req.validationErrors();` is there any problem with this line i am getting error `console.log("There may be errors");`.
while filling form i make sure that there is no field left empty.

Comment: Try not to check so many fields at once. Test one first and try to console.log(errors) to see what exactly issues is.

Comment: `[ { location: 'body',
    param: 'uname',
    msg: 'Username is required',
    value: undefined } ]`
Getting this kind of errors.

Comment: console.log(req.body) to see if you have succefully pass uname from client side.

Comment: that's what i am trying now but i am not getting `value` instead of this i am getting `undefined`

Comment: There might be issue in client side. Do you use form submit or ajax post ? You can use postman to debug serverside first and then fix the client side. When you debug client side use chrome dev tools or similar find the post request in network and chech if you have successed attach params.